# Twitter Bootstrap 3 RC1 horizontal scroll issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 RC1 and even though there is nothing but a row and a column, I can scroll horizontally just a little bit. I'd prefer not to have any horizontal scrolling at all.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could be a good idea to report your issue here instead: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/new

Comment: Thanks, I posted it there

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It has a bug because of negative margins;

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row {margin-right: -15px;margin-left: -15px;}
}
```

You can override bootstrap with this;

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .row { margin-right: 0; margin-left: 0; }
}
```

Check here also;
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/6686

Comment: This is now fixed with the release of Bootstrap RC3 - http://blog.getbootstrap.com/2013/08/13/bootstrap-3-rc2/

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else coming across this problem, what fixed it for me was wrapping all row/form/etc. elements in a `<div class="container">` block.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this problem without disturbing the bootstrap css and wait for a fix in the next version, so you can simply wrap your row by defining you own class .container-fluid with padding.

```
//Add this class to your global css file
<style>
   .container-fluid {
       padding: 0 15px;  
   }
</style>

   //Wrap your rows in within this .container-fluid 
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-3">content</div>
          <div class="col-md-9">content</div>
          <div class="col-md-3">content</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```